# Determining 0+ vs 0- inside a square root function

Tags: calculus

I have this limit and I am confused about how to determine 0+ vs 0-.
$ \lim_{ x \to 0^-} \frac{x^2 -1}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}$ Should I have to show something or just assume 0+ since 0- is not in the domain of definition of $\sqrt{x}$ and it would be senseless to be such in a question otherwise. The limit does not exist, it s $-\infty$ So, or I just have to get out a different clear expression with the power of two to determine in a clear way? Thanks

Comment: When $x$ is between $-1$ and $0$ the expression under the radical in the denominator is positive. so the square root there makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, it s not about there is an option where you say, well there is a definition error rather the limit exists or not. I am not talking about well definition, I am assuming that, I am asking whether I should also assume 0+ or I should try to show it.

Comment: Neither the question nor the comment is clear. It makes sense to ask about the limits from the right and from the left. You can then see which exist and whether if both exist they are equal.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, that s the normal procedure, what I mean is that, let s say we have the above function, not defined at 0. But of course if the instructor is asking you to compute the limit, you re not supposed to answer well limit 0- is undefined! So that means what is inside the square root since it amounts to 0, it should be 0+. Why I am saying this is because many problems I ve seen solutions to assume 0+ when it comes to square root with out any framing to show that it amounts to 0+. Hope it s clearer by now.

Comment: Not clear. The domain of that function includes all of a neighborhood of $0$ except $0$ so (if I were your instructor) I would _not_ expect you to "assume $0+$" Note too that the denominator is always positive. The square root does not come with a "$\pm$". Perhaps that is adding to your confustion.

Comment: Ok, let s consider this function, f(x) = sqrt{x^2 -1}, domain of def = ]-00, -1] union [1, +00[, now, if I am to compute the lim_(-1^-) frac{1}{f(x)} I would get +00, without me to get to know whether lim (-1)^- f(x) = 0+, because it should, why? Because (-1)^- is in the definition, and since it amounts to 0 inside the square root, it should amount to 0+. Clear?

Comment: Sorry, line three, i would get -00

Comment: You can't ask about the limit of that function from the left at $1$ because there are no nearby points in the domain there. No more back and forth in comments.

Comment: I didn t say at $1$, but at $-1^-$

Comment: At $-1$ you can't ask about a limit from the right.

Comment: It s from the left $-1^-$ that is <-2<x<-1

Answer (score 3):

If $-1<x<0$, then $x^3$ is negative and has smaller absolute value than $x$, so we have $-1<x<x^3<0$. Thus $x^3-x>0$ so its square root is well-defined.

Comment: Yeah, it s not about there is an option where you say, well there is a definition error rather the limit exists or not. I am not talking about well definition, I am assuming that, I am asking whether I should also assume 0+ or I should try to show it.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "assume/show $0+$". You need to determine what happens to $\sqrt{x^3-x}$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from below. The answer is that it approaches zero from above, and the *way* you show that is exactly the argument I gave in my answer that says $x^3-x>0$.

Comment: can you comment on my last comment above? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I suggest you speak with the instructor of your class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is true. As a general case, for any $a, b$ such that $a > b$, $a-b > 0$. This applies to negative values too. So everything you should do in your square root is see that, for the values approaching $0$ from the negatives, $x^3>x$, and therefore $x^3 - x > 0$.

This is what the other fellow said before me, with a little bit more of explanation. But all credits for him on answering the question.